# What is the current limit for a photon's rest mass?

Tags: photons, mass, measurements

Before you start yelling, I know that a photon according to theory has zero rest mass. But it is sort of difficult to measure zero, so what is the current best measurement upper limit of this zero? A few electronvolts? (The question is sort of similar to that it seems like the rest mass of the neutrino-s are not exactly zero although we believed that for a long time).

Comment: "A few eV" is an enormous amount of energy when you're talking about experimental limits.

Comment: Considering that we've measured plenty of photons with a _total_ mass less than a milli-electronVolt, it seems rather obvious that the rest mass is way lower than that!

Comment: Ooh, give me some slack! According to the answer I was only off by a factor of 10 to the power of 18 or so. Not too bad really ;-)

Comment: @J... Note that "a few eV" is the current upper limit for the mass of the heaviest neutrino.

Comment: @rob In the context of photons, I should say. Obviously something as stupendously exotic and elusive as the tau neutrino, with MeV scale energy, will have larger uncertainties. In terms of photons, a few eV is more than the total energy of all visible and longer photons.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The limit in the [2020 Particle Data Group Summary](https://pdg.lbl.gov/2020/listings/rpp2020-list-photon.pdf) is $m_\gamma < 10^{-18}\mathrm{eV} \approx 10^{-27}m_\text{proton}$, based on a 2007 analysis of the magnetohydrodynamics of the solar wind.  The [PDG reviews](http://pdg.lbl.gov) are excellent reading on these kinds of questions.

Comment: I know this is a little fast, but I will mark this as accepted answer due to the reference to PDG reviews, that I have been able to miss up to now.  Thank you!

Comment: To give some kind of handle on how low this number is its interesting to see that a (zero-mass) photon with 10^-18 electron volts of energy would have a wavelength about ten times longer than the Earth-Sun distance. Thus I believe that if photons DID have a rest mass at about that limit a photon would need to have a wavelength at least 10AU before its rest-mass energy surpassed its kinetic energy.